# How do find string if match (some lines before and after)

Tags: shell

If I want to Search "Finnish" then I want my output will be like

```
Raamatun tutkisteluja IV, mennessä Charles T. Russell                    56898
 [Subtitle: Harmagedonin taistelu]
 [Language: Finnish]
```

**How to find the chunk of string?????**

But My File Content is :

```
TITLE and AUTHOR                                                     ETEXT NO.

Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger

The Vicar of Morwenstow, by Sabine Baring-Gould                          56899
 [Subtitle: Being a Life of Robert Stephen Hawker, M.A.]

Raamatun tutkisteluja IV, mennessä Charles T. Russell                    56898
 [Subtitle: Harmagedonin taistelu]
 [Language: Finnish]

Raamatun tutkisteluja III, mennessä Charles T. Russell                   56897
 [Subtitle: Tulkoon valtakuntasi]
 [Language: Finnish]
```

Comment: Can you be more exact about 'before and after' ? Do you want the line above '[Language: Finnish]'

Comment: Assuming you have a Linux based system.

It looks like your text file contains a set of records which are separated from one another by means of empty lines. You can easily search through such a file by means of awk with the record separator `RS` an empty string. This would create the command `awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/Finnish/' file.txt`. More about awk on http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-book/ and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Answer (score -1):

`grep -A number_of_lines_after -B number_of_lines_before Finnish file`

Comment: In my file, there is all the book information store. So, When I search using author name then i  need all book info of that author like book name, author and textno.

For example, If I search by Finnish then Output will be below.

Raamatun tutkisteluja IV, mennessä Charles T. Russell 56898 
[Subtitle: Harmagedonin taistelu] 
[Language: Finnish]

and in my file, all book info is separated with newline